Vscode-compatible REGEX that searches for a hashtag in multiline text in between some delimiters (dashes -as first non-blank characters on the line)
I am trying to achieve this and I don't believe it can't be done with regex, albeit I would have probably done it with scripting already ...
I have a bunch of text files that have multi-line text that fits in between lines that start with a dash (as the first non-blank character on that line). So each such multi-line text might have, on the last line before the dash-starting line below, a line that starts with ">" and contains, somewhere on that line, a hashtag.
Here is one such example:
    - ffff
      - aaa
          * bbb
          * ccc

        - tttt
          * aaa 
          * bbb
          > #tag
    - tttt 
      * aaaa 
      * bbbb
      > #log
-

I have managed to get the text in between dashes but I can't seem to be able, for the life of me, to speciufy another rule, that in between those dashes there should be a line starting with ">" and containing the tag "#log" -for example:
(^\s*)(-[\s\S\n]+?(?=^\s*-))

Is there a way, with REGEX, to match each multiline text in between dash-starting lines that contains, on it's last line, ">.#log.$"?
I tried many many variations like tis one:
(^\s*)(-[\s\S\n]+?(?=>.*#log.*$\n\s*-))

This basically gets everything (greedy?), from the first dash in the file up to the line starting eith ">" that is followed by a newline starting with dash. So it does what it says it dows I just don't know how to tell it that I don't want any lines starting with dash in the match.
I somehow want to tell it to only consider the last dash-starting line (non-greedy?)...
Thank you for saving my sanity :)
Edit: tried to add this in a comment but it is very quirky:
expected output is:


- whatever text on \n
  any number of lines which might have "-" dashes in there, \n
  * lists \n
      * sublist \n
      etc \n
  also some #tags and the whole "block" ends with the following line \n
  > #tag1 #tag2 .... #log ... [maybe some links at the end, etc] \n


So basically everything between a dash and until the line that starts with > with no other intermediary lines that start with a dash (a dash might be there inside the line though)

I've put "\n" at the end of the lines because code block is not possible  


What do you want to get in the end (taking your sample string above as input)?

Try it like this (^\s*)(-.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*-).*)*\r?\n\s*>\s*#log\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*-).*)*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*-).*)*\r?\n)(?=^\s*-) See https://regex101.com/r/dkosL5/1

Tell me what is your expected output ? @sothor

expected output is:
    - whatever text on 
      any number of lines which might have "-" dashes in there,
      * lists
          * sublist
          etc
      also some #tags and the whole "block" ends with the following line
      > #tag1 #tag2 .... #log ... [maybe some links at the end, etc]

So basically everything between a dash and until the line that starts with > with no other intermediary lines that start with a dash (a dash might be there inside the line though)

I think you want to filter out this area of your input text:

So, for this regex should be:
(\-)[\s\w\n\*\>]*(\#log)

https://regex101.com/r/WSVznR/2

If you want to filter out data within hyphen(-) and #log, then your regex should be:
(?<![^\-])[\s\w\n\*\>]*(?=\#log)

https://regex101.com/r/SJuUK2/2
If it's contains some other special characters then add them accordingly.
Here, I'm used Regex Lookahead and Lookbehind concept

Thank you @RicardoSouza for your comment, which is really a valid scenario, which I completely escape before.
So, I update my changes according to that.

The presented solutions wouldn't work if the text contains one of the characters in #log (eg. if one of the lines of text contains an o, the expressions will not match). To make it clear: [^\#log]* means match any character that is not in this list (#, l, o, g) zero or more times.

Thank you @RicardoSouza for your important observation. I have update my changes...

thanks for posting. I tried both your regex-es(?) :) and i get, for both,
Invalid regular expression: Invalid escape


@sothor Share some images to check how're you validation that ..

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to select the text from lines starting with a dash - to the closest line that starts with a greater-than sign > and contains the hashtag #log anywhere in that line.
If that's the case, a possible solution is the following
^\s*?(-\s*?.+?\n(?:^\s*?[^-> ].+?\n)*?\s*?>.*?#log.*?$)

This matches a line starting with a -, then matches any following lines starting with anything that is not - or >, until if finds a line starting with > that contains #log in it.
https://regex101.com/r/e95h9x/1
An improved version of that is:
^\s*-\s*(\S[^\n]*\n(?:^\s*[^-> ][^\n]*\n)*\s*>.*?#log.*?$)

This version is more explicit about the characters and tries to avoid backtracking traps (when a quantifier can be matched by the expression right after it, causing many unnecessary iterations).
https://regex101.com/r/ZJ4hNZ/1

While this works as expected in a file-wide scenario, I couldn't test it against a folder-wide scope because it freezes my vscode ... perhaps there is a super wide search in there that runs and it's resource-heavy or something ...

@sothor, I added an improved version to the answer. That one should cause less backtracking and will be less cpu intensive.

This should take care of it, I tested in VSCode against your sample input and got two matches - the first chunk from * aaa to > #tag and then the second chunk from * aaaa to > # log
(?<=-.+\n)(?:[^-#]|\n)+#.+
So this will use a lookbehind to find a line starting with a hyphen but not include it, followed by a series of any character that's not a # or -, including newlines, up until it gets to a #, and then anything else out to the end of that line

Thanks for replying ... this is interesting, while this works in an in-file regex, it fails for the folder-wide regex with "Regex parse error: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length" ... :-/

@sothor ah that makes sense - if you can deal with having the - tttt show up as part of the result, you can change it from a lookbehind to a non-capturing group (?:-.+\n)(?:[^-#]|\n)+#.+.

I have updated it some by going through folder-wide search with my real-world data and got to this one:
(?:^\s+-.+\n)(?:[^-]|\n)+>.*#\w+.*$

But the ?:[^-] seems to match dashes anywhere in the text not only as the first character on the line...
New sample text to solve:
-
 - ffff
   - aaa
       * bbb
       * ccc
          > ddd eee #log
  - tttt
    * aaa 
    * bbb
    > #tag
 - tttt 
   * aaaa 
   * bbbb
   > #log
- aaa
   |-|-|
   | " #tag3 " | [[ — ]] |
  - 
  > #log
     - aaaa
     bbb-b[ #Tag3 ]
             > #log


hmm, it seems not possible to add code block markup inside comments ... ‍♂️

I see, ok yeah you'd want to make sure it starts at the beginning of a line and has nothing but spaces prior. This should work: (?:^\s+-.+\n)(?:[^-#]|\n)+#.+

Thanks all for answering. So far I have come, with your help, to this Regex that seems to cover all? situations I have in my real-world data:
(?:(^\s*)(-\s+.*\w.*\n))((?:^(?!\s*-).*\n)*)^\s*>(.*#\S+.*$)


Edit: if I have a line before a match that starts with a dash and contains no other character it is considered part of the match, which I don't want to. So, for example:
  -
        - aaa.   
          * IIII;
          * JJJ.
          >  #log 

The above regex will consider all the lines above as part of the match (https://regex101.com/r/8Xn1py/1). How can I modify this so it doesn't allow multiple lines that start with dash?

I is still not 100% of what I want (as the title explains), which is "all text between two lines that start with dash as the first non-blank character, with the condition that no intermediary lines can have a dash as the first non-blank character. So:
   - whatever text
line that doesn't start with dash but can have dashes, "-", after the first character
[...]
   line that doesn't start with dash (but has spaces in front of it and can have "-"-es after the first character)
   [...]
   > maybe some other tags #looked-for-tag maybe -even-more-tags
- 

I think I might have lucked out on it:
(?:(^\s*)(-\s*.*\w+.*\n))((?:^(?!\s*-).+\n)*?(?=^\s*-))

but I am not sure as I haven't had enough time to test it "in the wild"...
PS: I have also updated the Test String at https://regex101.com/r/WSVznR/3
I am sure there might be more efficient ways of achieving this. As I can see on regex101.com Debugger it takes hundreds of steps to get the results but that is wayyyy beyond my skill...

Glad you could get to a solution that works for you. My updated answer would have covered your case.
